# LDAP and Thin Clients

Tags: 12.04, lts, ldap, client

I currently have a Sun/Oracle Enterprise Directory Server setup.  I want to if possible authenticate my thin LTS clients to prevent the burden of local accounts and adhere to company policy. I have seen this document which outlines the procedure to authenticate Ubuntu clients to an existing Sun/Oracle Enterprise System Directory Server: -

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SunLDAPClientAuthentication

I have yet to try, but is it possible to apply the procedure to a thin client?  My assumption is after reading the document is that I’d simply need to mount and chroot the thin client image and then follow the procedure.  Has anyone attempted this before?

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!!!  Used the following procedure: -

http://forum.zentyal.org/index.php?topic=12925.0

Worked for me.